# Обработка форм на сайте

Tags: php

Первый раз собираюсь это делать.
Пробу написать web приложение на php. Оно должно получать текст в свою форму ввода от пользователя и после нажатия кнопки отправки - это приложение должно авторизоваться под заданными учетными данными на стороннем сайте и положить этот текст в форму удалённого сайта и нажать там кнопку сохранения. Я так понимаю это парсинг только в обратную сторону, так?
Как это реализовать, в какую сторону начать читать?

Comment: А можно адрес сайта где эта кнопка сохранения ?

Comment: Форма для ввода текста у меня локальная, а вот текст должен передаваться в яндекс веб мастре в раздел уникальные материалы и там сохраняться. Собственно выше поставил образную цель, что бы понять куда мне думать.

Comment: По сути дела вам нужно знать url куда отправлять запрос и каким методом он туда отправляется. Это можно узнать поковыряв код страницы через просмотр кода или к примеру через "Инструменты разработчика" в гугл хром

Comment: и потом сделать отправку через обычный POST запрос?

Comment: Да, авторизация это по сути форма отправляющая POST...

Answer (score 1):

[как авторизоваться на Яндексе](http://maksis.ru/avtorizaciya-v-yandekse-%E2%80%93-php-curl-i-cookies.html), при помощи этого можно понять как сделать первое и второе

[найдено в гугле](https://www.google.com.ua/search?q=php+%D0%B0%D0%B2%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F+%D0%BD%D0%B0+%D1%8F%D0%BD%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%B5&aq=f&oq=php+%D0%B0%D0%B2%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F+%D0%BD%D0%B0+%D1%8F%D0%BD%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%B5&aqs=chrome.0.57j0j62l2.9425&sugexp=chrome,mod=8&sourceid=chrome&client=ubuntu&channel=cs&ie=UTF-8)